# What is the Datatype for 10:00 AM PST in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table that need to store **Timeslot** such as 10:00 AM PST, 10:15 AM PST.... etc at a **constant interval of 15 Min**.

I am wondering if there is any Time datatype available for this kind of data?

I need to store them as 11:00 AM PST, 11:15 AM PST, 11:30 AM PST, 11:45 PM PST, 12:00 PM PST, 12:15 PM PST, 12:30 PST, 12:45 PM PST, 01:00 PM PST..... etc.

Also in future if the business requirement is for 20 min interval, I should be able to change it easily.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a [`time`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677243.aspx) data type you can use (SQL Server 2008).

```
CREATE TABLE Table1 ( Column1 time(7) )
```

The range is:

> 00:00:00.0000000 through 23:59:59.9999999

You can use a [`CHECK CONSTRAINT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188258.aspx) to ensure that the minutes part is one of (`0, 15, 30, 45`).

Comment: Is it possible to get constant interval of 15 min if we specify the start time?

Comment: I think this would be the better way to go. If down the road your requirements change and smaller intervals are required, you can change the constraint.

Comment: @Rita - it is up to you. Check Constraints are fairly flexible - you need to decide how to define them.

Comment: @Rita, for example, `alter table table add constraint chkTableInterval  check(datepart(minute, DateCreated) in (0, 15, 30, 45))`

Answer (score 3):

You could use the [`Time`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677243.aspx) data type.

If that's overkill for you since you only need to store the interval at the level of minutes, you could store the minutes since midnight, within the range 0-1339.

You might even consider storing the number of 15-minute intervals since midnight, such that `2:00 AM` is `8` and `2:15 AM` is `9` (though unless you can think of a great name for such a column, it wouldn't be very clear).

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to constrain a `time` to 15 minute intervals, the easiest way to do it would be to just store it in an `int` constrained between 0-100 (some daylight savings days have 25 hours) and calculate when the exact time is if you need it.  I've worked on a few large applications that have used this for stuff like weather forecasting data and it has worked quite well.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more? I need to store them as 11:00 AM PST, 11:15 AM PST, 11:30 AM PST, 11:45 PM PST, 12:00 PM PST, 12:15 PM PST, 12:30 PST, 12:45 PM PST, 01:00 PM PST..... etc 

Also in future if the business requirement is for 20 min interval, I should be able to change it easily.

Comment: midnight would be `0`, 12:15 AM would be `1`, etc.  The date and timezone would be stored in separate fields.  Jeff has edited his response to basically copy mine.

Comment: It can often look like someone has copied your answer - unfortunately StackOverflow doesn't show the first five minutes of revision history, which I think would conclusively demonstrate that didn't happen here (you posted about four minutes after me, so there's about a minute of leeway). I didn't even read your answer until I noticed you'd accused me of plagiarizing you, and I'd appreciate it if you'd delete your accusation, in which case I'll delete this too.